# How to prevent one of the projects in a solution from being built?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a VS solution with two projects: one is the actual code (which builds into a dll), the other is sample code that exercises the dll code.  Without deleting the sample code, is there a way I can prevent the build from outputting the sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open solution properties in Solution Explorer, right click, Properties, then Configuration Properties, then uncheck the projects you don't want to build in this configuration.

Check [Solution Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166577.aspx) on MSDN for details.

[image]

Comment: I deleted the bin directories, and it's now working... thanks for your help.

Comment: This gets you control over what projects are built. The one you run is set separately (right click project in the Solution Explorer and set one with `Set as Startup Project`. This lets you set it the way you like, including build one project and start debugging session with another.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new configuration that just includes the "real" code and build that.

Go to **Build > Configuration Manager...** then select `<New>` from the "Active solution configuration:" combo box.

You can copy a configuration from one of the existing ones and then just deselect your sample code project.